# Precisão de float64

Tags: tipagem, float, golang, valor-monetário

Por que o Go ao realizar o cálculo:

```
(1 * 0.09) + 0.36
```

retorna um float64 no seguinte formato `0.44999999999999996`?

Estou tentando realizar comparações com testes e o cálculo deveria ser `0.45` porque este comportamento e como faço para "arredondar" esse número?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O arredondamento se dá com a função [`math.Round()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Round). Porém nem tente usá-la para resolver o problema que tem aí.

O que deseja é exatidão e não precisão. Tipos de ponto flutuante binários não possuem exatidão, eles servem para cálculos aproximados apenas. Para valores monetários ou outros tipos de valores que precisam de exatidão o correto é usar o tipo [`Decimal`](https://godoc.org/github.com/shopspring/decimal). As pessoas ficam tentadas porque com arredondamento parece resolver o problemas, mas ele fica ali pronto para lhe causar problemas.

Para saber mais leia [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

E se ficou curioso, sim, a maioria dos programadores usam errado e trabalham com valores equivocados nos seus softwares.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Único problema desse pacote é que ele não é padrão, porém existe o math/big. Já ouvi recomendarem usar um int64 também para representar dinheiro. Sinceramente não sei qual a situação atual da linguagem e se já resolveram esse problema.